# Excel VBA Copying from Various cells from various Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Need some help coding in VBA Excel.
So currently, I have 100+ tables and have to manually input all the data to each table from many separate Excel file from each region.
You can view the table image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftLdE.png

My current code still depends on targeting a range of cells to copy which is not feasible considering if there is a change in the rows/columns.

Is there anyway to collectively get all the data from each region's Excel file and insert it?

Or is it possible to target a header or a table name so that it can fill in automatically?
Pardon me if the solution is so simple and have been asked before.

Thank you so much for the help.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim OpenSource As String
Dim OpenTarget As String
OpenSource = Application.GetOpenFilename("File Type, *.xlsm")
If OpenSource = "False" Then Exit Sub
OpenTarget = Application.GetOpenFilename("File Type, *.xlsm")
If OpenTarget = "False" Then Exit Sub
'## Open both workbooks first:

Set x = Workbooks.Open(OpenSource) 'Source File 'thisworkbook can implement here?
Set y = Workbooks.Open(OpenTarget) 'Destination File

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("Data").Range("C16:N16").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("C19:N19").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("C34:N34").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("C37:N37").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("C52:N52").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("C55:N55").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("C70:N70").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("C73:N73").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("C124:N124").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("C127:N127").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("C286:N286").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("C289:N289").Value

y.Sheets("Data").Range("R88:AC88").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R91:AC91").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R106:AC106").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R109:AC109").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R142:AC142").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R145:AC145").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R160:AC160").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R163:AC163").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R178:AC178").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R181:AC181").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R196:AC196").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R199:AC199").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R214:AC214").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R217:AC217").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R232:AC232").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R235:AC235").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R250:AC250").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R253:AC253").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("R268:AC268").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("R271:AC271").Value

y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG88:AR88").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG91:AR91").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG106:AR106").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("A109:AR109").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG142:AR142").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG145:AR145").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG160:AR160").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG163:AR163").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG178:AR178").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG181:AR181").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG196:AR196").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG199:AR199").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG214:AR214").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG217:AR217").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG232:AR232").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG235:AR235").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG250:AR250").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG253:AR253").Value
y.Sheets("Data").Range("AG268:AR268").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("AG271:AR271").Value


MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: If there was some criteria that the ranges were based on, you could use that to set a start and end row and a start and end column. In other words, is there any other pieces of information within the spreadsheet that leads you to be concerned about each of these ranges?

Comment: Is there any way you could upload one of the files so that we can have a look? For another project I used code which opens every Excel file in a selected folder and does the same operation (i.e. find Infos and copy them to a master file ) for all of them automatically. That might be applicable to you too?!

Comment: @MattCremeens the only criteria that I can think of is the Title of each Region and the Months, so basically its all the same kind of file which will be compiled later on by me. The concern will be if there is additional Regions to be added later on than the ranges will need to be expanded dynamically.

Comment: @InternInNeed Its somehow similar to what I need. For simplicity sake, so there is 2 sheets Main and Region 1 in the file. Each sheet represent 2 separate excel files. So I will need to copy the Total of each table from Region 1 to the rows in Main tables.Here is a link to the sample file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IynGuawSRwcHtDLSdua70Y73Yx2uN5H4Hy9vnR-dPuM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. as long as you know the starting point, you can dynamically count and copy rows, see modification to code below:

```
x.Sheets("Data").Range("C16:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("Data").Range("C19")
```

where i have put `Cells(Rows.Count,14)`, the 14 relates to column N.

Apply the same logic to the rest and you should be fine! let me know how this works as i have not tested it :)

Comment: It doesn't work as I get an empty box instead on the destination file. Let me get the code right, so first start from range C16 and Column N and ending with the last filled cell from the same row 16. and copy command is called.The Destination meanwhile starts from Range C19? Is it necessary to specify that it will end at N19 as well?

Comment: Sorry! please see the edit. the range now includes "C16:N". tested and works :)

Comment: Thanks!!! It works but a small issue though the table got misaligned. Not sure why.. Tried playing around with changing xlUp and the range but still no result Image:http://imgur.com/a/2k1tG

Comment: @Collin is it actually a table or just formatted cells to look like a table? It works fine on my excel, no offset occuring

Comment: Yes it's a table. Don't know why it creates an offset.

Comment: May you please show me the screenshot of the tables before you execute the code? I simulated this in excel by creating a table and it works fine. I need to see the layout of yours

Comment: There is no offset, have a look at both screenshots you sent me. Your table is incorrectly created, the middle section seems to have extra rows? :)

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong picture. Here is the right one. http://imgur.com/a/sayXu

Comment: If there is any data below the last row of the table this will impact the copying. If this is the case, just insert a blank row and you should be fine

Comment: There is no data below the last row of the table. There is only a single row gap between the same tables. I still can't get it to align properly according to the table. Any help here?

Comment: hmm perhaps you have not applied the code modifcation correctly to all of the lines, can you attach the edited code?

Answer (score 1):

I think we have the Destination and Source the wrong way around as well.
How do I put the code in reverse? E.g. The source should be from row C19:N19 of the source file and to be copied to row C14:N14 of the destination file.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim OpenSource As String
Dim OpenTarget As String
OpenSource = Application.GetOpenFilename("File Type, *.xlsm")
If OpenSource = "False" Then Exit Sub
OpenTarget = Application.GetOpenFilename("File Type, *.xlsm")
If OpenTarget = "False" Then Exit Sub


Set x = Workbooks.Open(OpenSource) 'Source File
Set y = Workbooks.Open(OpenTarget) 'Destination File

x.Sheets("Data").Range("C14:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("Data").Range("C19")

MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: I've got it working to the right rows, but I can't get it to paste only values instead. Any help here?
x.Sheets("Data").Range("C19").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("Data").Range("C14:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: ah yes i just looked at the original code and the destination and source rows are different. should'nt C14 be C16? as the range?

Comment: And do paste value, just copy the newly pasted range, and paste value it :)